# Problem in Recovering the Lost Data from the Database files (.mdf and .ldf)

Tags: sql-server-2008, recover

Recently, one of our clients has deleted two million rows from a table.

Here the problem is the database is not taken backup. I have only the master data file (.mdf) and Log data file (.ldf) with me.

I have downloaded some demo version of Sql tool, through which i am able to open the .mdf file . When i opened the .mdf file using the Sql tool all the lost data is there in the .mdf file but i cant save or export the view of the Lost data from .mdf file from the tool until i purchase it.

I had followed many steps that has shown in MSDN and various websites to recover but with all a failure. Can any one help me, what is best process to recover the deleted data and put in .ldf file.
One of the Sites which I have referred to recover the data is [Recover Lost Data](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/f1445ab6-7f0d-47b3-a555-f9b114088433)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the cost of losing the data? What is the cost over time of losing the data--that is, is it more and more the longer the data remains lost? Compare this cost with the cost of the tool you have found that (apparently) works, and factor in the cost of the time it has and is taking you to find a different solution. It seems likely that, unless they're charging ridiculous amounts of money [*can you post the product and cost?*], you'd be better off biting the bullet, paying them, and using the product right away, with the (implicit) guarantee of a refund if it doesn't work.

Another option is to get a transaction log reading program that can read and work with data stored in the transaction log... but if you're not doing backups, then your databases are (hopefully!) in Simple recovery mode, and depending on how active your databases are that data may have long-since been dropped from the transaction log. However, all such programs that I've heard about also have licensing fees.

Because yes, recovering deleted data from a SQL Server database is a hard thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I cant buy that Tool right now. I know by some Particular Methods using Some queries we can Recover the Data, but not Clearly. So, I posted my Question Here.